# Not able to install APK on Selenium Grid Node

Tags: java, android, appium, selenium-grid

I have set up a Selenium Grid having 1 MAC - 10.9 and 2 Windows Machine- Windows 7.

I am executing Appium scripts on this grid environment.

I am able to execute iPhone scripts on MAC machine but not able to even install the apk file on Windows machine.

I have kept the apk file in the node machine and providing its path from the script using "app" DesiredCapabilities.

Every time I execute Appium throws error -

```
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.871 sec <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
setTemepraturesAndroid(com.testcases.SetTemperatures)  Time elapsed: 1.856 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Only a (zipped) app/apk files can be installed using this endpoint (WARNING: The server did not provide any sta
cktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 78 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.43.1', revision: '5163bceef1bc36d43f3dc0b83c88998168a363a0', time: '2014-09-10 09:43:55'
System info: host: 'kdsksadaskjd', ip: 'XX.XX.XX.XX', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_25'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Capabilities [{app=./Arena_prod.apk, appPackage=com.android.arena, networkConnectionEnabled=true, warnings={}, databaseEnabled=false, deviceN
ame=Nexus5, platform=LINUX, desired={app=./Arena_prod.apk, appPackage=com.android.arena, autoLaunch=false, platformVersion=4.4.4, automationN
ame=Appium, browserName=Nexus5, platformName=Android, deviceName=Nexus5}, autoLaunch=false, platformVersion=4.4.4, webStorageEnabled=false, locationCon
textEnabled=false, automationName=Appium, browserName=Nexus5, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=Android}]
Session ID: 009dffae-2e34-4dc0-a208-bf54ed230c7c
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
        at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:180)
        at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.installApp(AppiumDriver.java:217)
        at com.commons.Utils.launchApplication(Utils.java:299)
        at com.keywords.LoginToApp.run(LoginToApp.java:21)
        at com.testcases.SetTemperatures.setTemepraturesAndroid(SetTemperatures.java:65)
```

Results :

```
Failed tests:
  SetTemperatures.setTemepraturesAndroid:65 » WebDriver Only a (zipped) app/apk ...

Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

If I zip the apk file, I am getting the following error -

```
Running TestSuite
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.7 sec <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
setTemepraturesAndroid(com.testcases.SetTemperatures)  Time elapsed: 0.671 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: Bad app: C:\Selenium-Grid\Appium\Appium\node_modul
es\appium\Arena_prod.zip. App paths need to be absolute, or relative to the appium server install dir, or a URL to compressed file, or a special app na
me. cause: Error: Command failed: 'xargs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 343 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.43.1', revision: '5163bceef1bc36d43f3dc0b83c88998168a363a0', time: '2014-09-10 09:43:55'
System info: host: 'hjasdkjashdklajsd', ip: 'XX.XX.XX.XXX', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_25'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
        at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:180)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:240)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:126)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:153)
        at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:109)
        at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:39)
        at com.commons.Utils.launchApplication(Utils.java:271)
        at com.keywords.LoginToApp.run(LoginToApp.java:21)
        at com.testcases.SetTemperatures.setTemepraturesAndroid(SetTemperatures.java:65)
```

Results :

```
Failed tests:
  SetTemperatures.setTemepraturesAndroid:65 » SessionNotCreated A new session co...

Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[ERROR] There are test failures.
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first log (when using the apk) you seem to be giving the following path for the app:

> app=./Arena_prod.apk

Is this correct? If you are on Windows, can you try with the .apk file but providing the full path like you did in the second case with the zip?

e.g.: C:\Selenium-Grid\Appium\Appium\node_modul
es\appium\Arena_prod.apk